# Python shell command produces too much output in the console (windows)

Tags: python, windows, scrapy

Is it possible to run some Python command to not see so much ballast output in the console? I am talking now about running Scrapy where I see tons of not needed texts that disallow to see some meaningful output only.

But I see some ballast in there also when running e.g. `pip install`. Not helpful at all.

[image: a sample of a screenful of output]

Comment: which type of text you want to print? did you use logging of python?

Comment: on this link https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#how-to-run-our-spider is declared some output i should see. but i am unable to see it due thousands of not needed lines like shown above.

Comment: It looks like you are in debug mode! Did you start with the -v flag by any chance?

Comment: i am not a python guy ok? so i have no clue about some -v flag, that's why i am asking. starting with -v what? scrapy?

Comment: Do you get the `pip install` stuff every time you run your code (not shown ...)?

Comment: i saw it always, it was a python running the verbose mode, i explained it below.

Answer (score 2):

Ok solved partly thanks to Steve Barnes and partly to my knowledge haha. I had set an environment variable `PYTHONVERBOSE=1` had to remove it and then it works as expected. Good.

Comment: This is a very useful answer! Do you have any idea where the environment variable came from? I suppose you didn't set it yourself – perhaps it was an option in an installer?

Comment: i have no clue, most likely it was set somehow automatically yes. but of course it is possible to set it also manually.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the materials found on scrapy's log [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html), it looks like you can enable or disable certain levels of log output with command line args:

```
--loglevel/-L LEVEL
```

where `LEVEL` is one of the debug levels. Additionally, if you would like no output, it appears there is the command line option:

```
--nolog
```

Comment: it looks like python related not scrapy